# How to know that a device connected to chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm working on app that can cast some data on Chromecast via [remote display](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote#run-the-remote-display-service) . In my app I can have behavior that user can leave screen and after some time return there one more time. But I have to know that device is connected to Chromecast, because app has to show another data in this way. Two classes below I use to connect to Chromecast(only this two classes, I don't use anything else). I thought maybe MediaRouter has some data about connection, but I didn't find anything. So my question is, How to detect that current  device is connected to chromecast&

ChromecastController.java

```
public class ChromecastController implements MediaRouterCallback.IChromecastCallback {

    private MediaRouterCallback mMediaRouterCallback;
    private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
    private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;

    public void initMediaRouter(MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton, FragmentActivity activity, MediaRouterCallback.IChromecastCallback callback) {
        // Configure Cast device discovery
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(M2MAppImpl.getContext());
        mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                .addControlCategory(
                        CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(CAST_ID ) )
                .build();
        mediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
        mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback(activity, M2MApp.getContext());
    }

    public void onStart() {
        mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
                MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);
    }

    public void onStop() {
        mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
    }

}
```

MediaRouterCallback.java

```
public class MediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

    public static final String TAG = MediaRouterCallback.class.getName();

    private CastDevice mSelectedDevice;
    private FragmentActivity activity;
    private Context mContext;

    public MediaRouterCallback(FragmentActivity activity, Context context){
        this.activity = activity;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected " + info.getName());

        mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle( info.getExtras() );

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                activity.getClass());
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext, 0, intent, 0);

        CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.NotificationSettings settings =
                new CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.NotificationSettings.Builder()
                        .setNotificationPendingIntent(notificationPendingIntent).build();

        CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.startService(
                M2MApp.getContext(),
                PresentationService.class, ChromecastController.CAST_ID,
                mSelectedDevice, settings,
                new CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.Callbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onServiceCreated(CastRemoteDisplayLocalService castRemoteDisplayLocalService) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CHROMECAST onServiceCreated");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRemoteDisplaySessionStarted(
                            CastRemoteDisplayLocalService service) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CHROMECAST onRemoteDisplaySessionStarted");
                        // initialize sender UI
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onRemoteDisplaySessionError(
                            Status errorReason){
                        Log.d(TAG, "CHROMECAST onRemoteDisplaySessionError " + errorReason);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRouteUnselected( MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected " + info.getName());
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [MediaRouter.RouteInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.RouteInfo.html) which you get in the [onRouteSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.Callback.html#onRouteSelected%28android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter,%20android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo%29) callback. `getDeviceType()` should be the way to go.

Comment: But what if user leave this screen and return there again. How will I know about RouteInfo in this way?

Comment: You will get the onRouteUnselected callback when he disconnects fron the chromecast and the  onRouteSelected again  when he reconnects.

Comment: But if user leaves screen, app won't have this callback(because this callback connected to screen). And when he'll return to screen back, it won't receive anything(because chromecast already connected or disconnected).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found how to manage it. Also it's solution from cast remote sample. I don't know why I didn't look at it before)

```
private boolean isRemoteDisplaying() {
    return CastRemoteDisplayLocalService.getInstance() != null;
}
```

it returns true if CastRemoteDisplayLocalService is working.